# How to format a DateTime like "Oct. 10, 2008 10:43am CST" in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

Is there a clean way to format a DateTime value as "Oct. 10, 2008 10:43am CST".

I need it with the proper abbreviations and the "am" (or "pm") in lower case etc etc.

I've done it myself but it's ugly so I'm looking for a different take on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Since the "tt" format string specifier only outputs upper case, you'll have to modify that yourself. Also, DateTimes do not store the name of the timezone, only an offset.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string ampm = dt.ToString("tt").ToLower();
string output = string.Format("{0:MMM. d, yyyy h:mm}{1}", dt, ampm);
```

Comment: cheatsheet no longer available

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTimeObject.ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy hh:mmtt");
```

not sure about CST.

If you want more combinations see this link:

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your server is configured to CST:

```
string format = dateTime.ToString("mmm. dd, YYYY HH:MM tt ")
    .Replace(" AM ", "am")
    .Replace(" PM ", "pm") +
    " CST";
```

Comment: close, but there's no space before AM or PM

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
myDateTime.ToString("MMM. d, yyyy hh:mmtt \C\S\T");
```