# What date format should be set to show am/pm in lower case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing the MVC 3 application.
In the view I am displaying the name along with created date time.
It displayed as a

> Nick Moris  27-Mar-13 11:49 AM <--

but I want to display in

> Nick Moris  27-Mar-13 11:49 am <--

I have write the below line of code in the partial class for the date time property.

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yy hh:mm tt} ")]
   public System.DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
```

and in the View I am using below code...

```
@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy a\\t h:mmtt"))
```

What changes I have to made in the date format ? 
It showing error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get AM/PM for a date time in lowercase using only a datetime format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499393/get-am-pm-for-a-date-time-in-lowercase-using-only-a-datetime-format)

Comment: Above solution is not working at all...giving error...

Comment: It seems you have two problemas here. Why do you have two different formats, one in the view model and one in the view? Which one do you want?

Answer (score 6):

You could format it in the view without using the `DisplayFor` helper:

```
@item.CommentDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm")  @item.CommentDateTime.ToString("tt").ToLower()
```

In this case you no longer need the `DisplayFormat` attribute on your view model.

Comment: This is actually a good solution for the issue. Just replace the `@Html.DisplayFor` part with this