# How to parse "string" to "DateTime" with "a. m." or "p. m." format (not AM/PM)?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to convert this `DateTime` string(`"6/12/2018  12:00:03 a. m."`) to `DateTime` type using the function `DateTime.ParseExact()`.

I converted the `string` using this option and it works:

```
var date = "6/01/2018  12:00:03 a. m.";
var x=Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Also I was able to convert this string(`"6/12/2018  12:00:03"`) using `DateTime.ParseExact()` but when the date doesn´t contain the indicator `a. m.` or `p. m.`:

```
var date = "6/01/2018  12:00:03";
var x=DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How can I convert that datetime string when the time part contains the `a. m.` or `p. m.` part using `DateTime.ParseExact()` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string containing AM/PM to DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672191/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-am-pm-to-datetime)

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow - not really , the AM and PM strings are non-standard

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime("6/12/2018  12:00:03 a. m.")` fails and throws an exception, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/FfO76R.  In what locale were you parsing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [the `tt` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-tt-custom-format-specifier) are for.

```
var date = "6/01/2018  12:00:03 am";
var x = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But remember, this `tt` specifier does *not* parse `a. m.` or `a.m.` strings. If your strings have those, you *have t*o manipulate your strings like removing dots and/or spaces between `a` and `m` etc.. It also parse `AM` and `PM` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to standardize the AM and PM strings first

```
var dateStr = "6/01/2018  12:00:03 a. m.";

var cleanDate = dateStr.Replace("a. m.", "AM").Replace("p. m.","PM");
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(cleanDate, "d/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `a. m.` and `p. m.` are nonstandard designators for AM and PM, you will need to create your own custom [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) based on your desired locale (you are using the invariant locale currently) and modify its [`AMDesignator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_DateTimeFormatInfo_AMDesignator) and [`PMDesignator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_DateTimeFormatInfo_PMDesignator) properties.  Then you can parse using the [`"tt"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-tt-custom-format-specifier) format specifier as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53656509/3744182) by [Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-g%c3%b6n%c3%bcl) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28672247/3744182) by [Complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2585090/complexity), passing the custom `DateTimeFormatInfo` as the [`IFormatProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) to [`DateTime.ParseExact(string s, string format, IFormatProvider provider)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_):

```
// Construct an invariant DateTimeFormatInfo and modify its AMDesignator and PMDesignator.
// The DateTimeFormat must be cloned since the global instance is read-only.
var formatInfo = (DateTimeFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.Clone();
formatInfo.AMDesignator = "a. m.";
formatInfo.PMDesignator = "p. m.";

var x = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss tt", formatInfo);
```

For performance reasons you may want to statically cache your `DateTimeFormatInfo` as shown, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499407).

**Alternatively**, there are several cultures that do use `a. m.` and `p. m.` as AM and PM designators, mainly Spanish and Catalan, and your app may be running with one of these cultures as the [current culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.7.2).  You can discover all such cultures as follows:

```
foreach (var info in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    if (info.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator == "a. m." && info.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator == "p. m.")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Culture {0} ({1}) has the required AM and PM designators.", info.DisplayName, info.Name);
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
Culture Catalan (ca) has the required AM and PM designators.
Culture Catalan (Andorra) (ca-AD) has the required AM and PM designators.
Culture Catalan (Catalan) (ca-ES) has the required AM and PM designators.
Culture Valencian (Spain) (ca-ES-valencia) has the required AM and PM designators.
Culture Catalan (France) (ca-FR) has the required AM and PM designators.
Culture Catalan (Italy) (ca-IT) has the required AM and PM designators.
Culture Spanish (Equatorial Guinea) (es-GQ) has the required AM and PM designators.
Culture Spanish (Mexico) (es-MX) has the required AM and PM designators.
Culture Spanish (Philippines) (es-PH) has the required AM and PM designators.
```

And you can examine the AM and PM designators of the current culture by printing to the console:

```
Console.WriteLine("Current culture AMDesignator=\"{0}\" and  PMDesignator=\"{1}\".",
                  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator,
                  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator);
```

You could parse your `date` string in any of these cultures and get your desired result:

```
var formatInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-MX");

var x = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss tt", formatInfo);
```

And if your user's current culture is one of these cultures, you could pass [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netframework-4.7.2) (or [`CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=netframework-4.7.2) if appropriate):

```
var x = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FfO76R).